# When an equation determines a linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I show that equations determines a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$?
For example the equation

$$2x-3y=5$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^2$, it has to be a line through the origin, because it has to contain the zero vector, plus it has to be closed under addition and scalar multiplication. If you add two vectors on a line or multiply a vector on a line by a scalar, you will get a vector still on that line. This one line doesn't go through the origin. If you plug in $[0,0]$, the equality doesn't hold. However, it is, very broadly speaking, a "[shifted subspace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_%28geometry%29)", something [affine geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry) deals with.

Answer (score 0):

Check if it goes through the origin and that the vectors are closed under addition along with multiplication (scalar). That is not the case with this line.